# WSE3.0 usage via PHP scripts

Tags: php, web-services, wse

Is it possible to have PHP communicate with WSE3.0 (microsoft).

I know it runs a RBO/LBO system for communicating between current software and the server.
But I'm trying to integrate a web based version via PHP.

Comment: Oh boy, I had no idea.  I was asked if PHP could communicate with a WSE (LBO/RBO) web-based server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WSE is obsolete.  Thanks John Saunders.